# Extracting all uppercase words following each other from string

Tags: python, string, list, uppercase

Out of a string like this `"A B c de F G A"` I would like to get the following list: `["A B", "F G A"]`. That means, I need to get all the sequences of uppercase words.

I tried something like this:

```
text = "A B c de F G A"
result = []
for i, word in enumerate(text.split()):
    if word[0].isupper():
        s = ""
        while word[0].isupper():

            s += word
            i += 1
            word = text[i]

        result.append(s)
```

But it produces a the following output: `['A', 'BB', 'F', 'G', 'A']`

I suppose it happens because you can't skip a list element by just incrementing `i`. How can I avoid this situation and get the right output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = "A B c de F G A"
new_s = [' '.join(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s.split(), key=str.isupper) if a]
```

Output:

```
['A B', 'F G A']
```

Comment: Great, thank you! If I also want to extract words that include a lowercase letter ("Aaa"), I use key=lambda x:x[0].isupper()

Comment: @ValeriaS.you can use `key=str.istitle` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` to split a string with a regex.

```
import re

def get_upper_sequences(s):
    return re.split(r'\s+[a-z][a-z\s]*', s)
```

### Example

```
>>> get_upper_sequences( "A B c de F G A")
['A B', 'F G A']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example will extract all uppercase words following each other from a string:

```
string="A B c de F G A"

import re
[val for val in re.split('[a-z]*',string.strip()) if val != " "]
```

Comment: The output is incorrect- you need to strip the strings to remove the leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: This is the output i am getting - ['A B ', ' F G A']. Could explain what is the difference and example of output you are expecting.

Comment: The output of this code is `['A B ', ' F G A']` but it *should* be `['A B', 'F G A']` (notice the lack of leading/trailing spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution without `itertools` or `re`:

```
def findTitles(text):
    filtered = " ".join([x if x.istitle() else " " for x in text.split()])
    return [y.strip() for y in filtered.split("  ") if y]

print(findTitles(text="A B c de F G A"))
#['A B', 'F G A']

print(findTitles(text="A Bbb c de F G A"))
#['A Bbb', 'F G A']
```